# Update sibling element css based on width of preceding element in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css

My layout currently breaks on 320px resolution (.info drops below .icon and breaks the layout) and I'm lost as to how about preventing it from breaking.

The .num info(number) is being loaded dynamically, and could be anything from 0 - 2147483647. If the screen resolution is not wide enough to show the .num and the .unread on one line, instead of breaking, I would like the .unread to drop down to the next line (display:block applied to it?). I tried to think of a way to use only css, then though I could use js to apply class if more than 2 digits are present, but this direction still doesn't seem right if the resolution is wider and could show more digits. E.G - 1000px could show many more digits... I would want it to stay on one line in this case.

My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
      body{
        padding:20px;
      }
      .wrapper {
        background-color:#cccccc;
        border-radius:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:2px solid black;
      }
      .icon {
        font-size:40px;
        padding:12px;
        display:block;
      }
      .icon, .info {
        float:left;
      }
      .info {
        border-left:1px solid black;
        padding-left: 15px;
      }
      .info h3 {
        font-size:16px;
        margin:10px 0 0;
      }
      .info p {
        margin:10px 0;
      }
      .num {
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:20px;
      }
      .unread {
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
                <div class="icon">X</div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>Header Information</h3>
                    <p>
                        <a class="num">23</a> 
                        <span class="unread">Unchecked Voicemails to Date</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/18Mids4M3SupNwOT8ocP?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to add a width to the .info container and make the elements inside of .info p display:inline-block.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
      body{
        padding:20px;
      }
      .wrapper {
        background-color:#cccccc;
        border-radius:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:2px solid black;
      }
      .icon {
        font-size:40px;
        padding:12px;
      }
      .icon, .info {
          float:left;
      }
      .info {
        border-left:1px solid black;
        padding-left:15px;
        width:60%;
      }
      .info h3 {
        font-size:16px;
        margin:10px 0 0;
      }
      .info p {
        margin:5px 0 15px;
      }
      .info span {
        display:inline-block;
      }
      .num {
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
                <div class="icon">X</div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>Header Information</h3>
                    <p>
                      <a class="num">2</a>
                      <span class="unread">Unopened Voicemails</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NanIRaMcK9AJvpNEQG3Z?p=preview